# on click event not working after first on click event.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie to jquery. I have a page where I have two buttons. One of them is edit button, and the other one is delete button. When I click edit button it removes these two button and at the same place( the place where delete and edit button were before) I add three elements one of them is "save" button. This save button has a class - "save-btn". I select this button by jquery class selector. And onclick it should do something. But when I click nothing happens. Can anyone suggest whats wrong and give a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 "></div>

    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <div class="form-tile">
            <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {% crispy form %}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 tile">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <h2 style="margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 0px;text-align: center">Today's Purchase</h2>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for item in items %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary edit-btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete-btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 "></div>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript

```
    <script>
$(function(){
    $(".edit-btn").click(function(){
        var custom_form = '<td><input type="text" size="10"></td><td><input type="text" size="10"></td> <td><button class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</i></button> </td>'
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent().html(custom_form);
    });

   $(".save-btn").click(function(){
        alert("asnlas");
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I think the class is not binding with jQuery during document ready. To make it work try this.
$(document).on('click', '.save-btn', function() { alert("asnlas"); }); 
Instead of  $(".save-btn").click(function(){alert("asnlas");});

Answer (score 2):

when you create an element you must assign the event at the same time

Try this....

```
$(function(){
$(".edit-btn").click(function(){
    var custom_form = '<td><input type="text" size="10"></td><td><input type="text" size="10"></td> <td><button class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</i></button> </td>'
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent().html(custom_form);

     $(".save-btn").click(function(){
         alert("asnlas");
     });
});

});
```